# Sending multiple patches under the same subject via git send-email

Tags: git, email, patch, mailing-list, git-send-email

I want to send emails via git send-email in a way that the appear linked in the inbox of the receiver.

For example
Topic Name
   '--> [PATCH 01/02] Added File1
      '--> [PATCH 02/02] Added File2

How do I go about doing that?. I tried sending emails to my account on gmail, but for every patch sent, it creates a new thread.

Comment: `git send-email` sends e-mails with proper threading. The gmail web interface does not display threading properly, it just relies on the e-mail Subject. Use a proper e-mail client, e.g. Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation details how to [sending Patches with git send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/MyFirstContribution#howto-git-send-email).
The alternative is [GitGitGadget](https://gitgitgadget.github.io/).

However, regarding `send-email`, make sure to use Git 2.34+ (Q4 2021):

Even when running "[`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd29bcf9136c6cb96dba3bb79c532b3b215fb9d8/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> without its own threaded discussion support, a threading related header in one message is carried over to the subsequent message to result in an unwanted threading, which has been corrected with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit e082113](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0821134846b10952efc0737b9e32ca8226f0a4d) (30 Aug 2021) by [Marvin Häuser (`mhaeuser`)](https://github.com/mhaeuser).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd29bcf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd29bcf9136c6cb96dba3bb79c532b3b215fb9d8), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0821134846b10952efc0737b9e32ca8226f0a4d): avoid incorrect header propagation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Marvin Häuser</sup>

> If multiple independent patches are sent with `send-email`, even if the "`In-Reply-To`" and "`References`" headers are not managed by `--thread` or `--in-reply-to`, their values may be propagated from prior patches to subsequent patches with no such headers defined.
>
> To mitigate this and potential future issues, make sure all global patch-specific variables are always either handled by command-specific code (e.g. threading), or are reset to their default values for every iteration.